# Bug in background colours

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There is a bug occurring on both the Puzzling main site and meta, as you scroll down instead of grading, the background repeats:

[image: screen shot 1]

[image: screen shot 2]

Don't know if this is site specific (this is on puzzling), though others have suggested so as we are the only ones with a graded background.

I'm on Chrome, haven't tested other browsers.

A couple of others have said in chat its happening to them too, one after he reloaded the page, so I don't know if there has been any work behind the scenes going on.

One is on Chrome the other on Firefox, so not browser specific

---

EDIT: Above bug fixed but new one identified.

As you scroll down now the background doesn't scroll, not a major bug but a bug all the same.

Comment: What site is this happening on?

Comment: @Oded puzzling, will add in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We changed some site-wide CSS that caused this bug. Should be fixed now!

Comment: Thanks! I have seen a few other questions reporting bugs linked to the CSS changes, so thought it might be that

Comment: Umm... actually there is a new bug. The background now stays still and doesn't scroll down as you do.

Comment: We had to apply `height: 100%` to `html` site-wide for some footer-specific changes. Applying `background-attachment: fixed` to your network's `body` solves the tiling issues you had, but you're right, the background doesn't scroll. Not sure how to maintain scrollability while fixing your issue. Can you live with it? 

Comment: Like I said in the question, its not a big deal, but its still a bug. If you can, then I think the community would prefer it fixed, but if its a major hassle for you, then don't worry about it, the community will understand and its not that a drastic change so we'll live with it. Who knows? Change can be good :P Thanks for your help all the same

Comment: Why no diamond here so that you can mark as completed yourself? :)